# How to use Chef to handle code deployment on existing nodes in a continuous integration environment?

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, chef-infra

In a continuous integration/delivery scenario (Windows), what command would I run on my server nodes to let have them deploy the new version?

I understand that recipes are idempotent/re-runnable, however, how do I let all the chef-clients know that a new revision of the code is now available?

Comment: That question is somewhat similar. The question mentions that the chef-client can detect `state change` and redeploy, how do I make that state change? If I can get it to redeploy the code based on the state change (i.e. a new revision of the code), that would work for me.

Comment: Correct the chef run needs to detect whether there is a need to upgrade in order to be idpotent. Personally I prefer to deploy to a directory with a release number in the name, another approach to take is to set a chef node attribute. For some more ideas on application deployment using chef checkout the artifact cookbook. https://github.com/RiotGames/artifact-cookbook

Comment: How does Chef know to redeploy if the directory has an old release number? Where is that stored/changed? If you set a node attribute, how does Chef know that the node attribute is not the latest or that it needs to redeploy? I'm having a hard time understanding how Chef knows when to do the deployment.

Comment: You've identified some of the complexities of trying to use chef to deploy applications. To answer your questions, assume the simplest scenario where your write a new cookbook version for each version of your app. It then becomes trivial to check for the directory of the current app version and the presence of the previous release directory can be used to trigger any upgrade or migration activities. If you want a generic cookbook then you are best advised to checkout what other people are doing. I advise looking at the "ark", "artifact" and "application" cookbooks.